# Random Array of Objects & Properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, binary-search

so I have an array in my code below but one of my requirements for the assignment is to have a very LARGE array of objects around like 10,000 objects. My teacher was saying that the computer can just keep generating random objects for you given how many you want so in my case like 10,000. I'm just confused about how I would do that, any help or suggestions are really appreciated thank you!

```
  class Shoe {
      constructor(name, price, type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.type = type;
      }
  }

  var shoes = [
     new Shoe('Nike AirMax 90', '120', 'Casual'),
     new Shoe('Jordan Retro 1', '110', 'Casual'),
     new Shoe('Jadon Doc Martens', '250', 'Seasonal boots'),
     new Shoe('Adidas X Ghosted', '110', 'Athletic'),
     new Shoe('Nike Vapourmax Flyknit', '250', 'Casual'),
     new Shoe('Aldo Loafers', '130', 'Formal'),
     new Shoe('Timberlands', '199', 'Seasonal boots'),
     new Shoe('Converse High Tops', '70', 'Casual'),
     new Shoe('Converse Low Tops', '80', 'Casual'),
     new Shoe('Adidas NMDs', '110', 'Athletic'),
     new Shoe('Heels', '130', 'Formal'),
     new Shoe('Nike AirForce', '150', 'Casual')
  ];

  function bubbleSort(shoes) {
    var swapped;
    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < shoes.length - 1; i++) {
        if (+shoes[i].price > +shoes[i + 1].price) {
           var temp = shoes[i];
           shoes[i] = shoes[i + 1];
           shoes[i + 1] = temp;
           swapped = true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);
    return shoes;
   }

   bubbleSort(shoes);
   console.log('Bubble Sort:\n', shoes);
```

Comment: @Barmar I tried doing that, but I think I typed it wrong or something cuz it just had no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a perfect job for a loop. You have to create helper functions that generate random names and prices and types.

For the `name`, we'll use:

```
function randomName(n) {
  let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqestuvwxyz";
  let name = "";
  
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    name += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  }

  return name;
}
```

This function generates strings of a specific length, but those strings are just gibberish which I guess is not very important.

For the `price`, we'll use:

```
function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

For the `type`, we'll just use `randomName`.

Then we use a `for` loop to populate the `shoes` array like so:

```
var shoes = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  shoes.push(new Shoe(randomName(20), randomNumber(50, 5000), randomName(7)));
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
class Shoe {
  constructor(name, price, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

function randomName(n) {
  let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqestuvwxyz";
  let name = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    name += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  }

  return name;
}

function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}


var shoes = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  shoes.push(new Shoe(randomName(20), randomNumber(50, 5000), randomName(7)));
}

console.log(shoes);
```

Comment: and then if I had to bubble sort I would just continue with what i had down below right?

Comment: also if i do this should I delete my class or delete my 'shoes' array?

Comment: @28space_junkiee you should keep the class definition. Just replace the code `var shoes = [ /* all those lines */ ]` with my code. See the **Demo:** code to get an idea of what should be replaced

Comment: @28space_junkiee and if your bubble sort code is correct it should work as expected without any modification

Comment: I have another question if you want to answer it you can but you don't have to so don't worry! So I have to implement a binary search function to and I was just wondering how I could implement it

Comment: It might be better to ask a new question as per SO guidelines. Please also remember to mark @ibrahimmahrir 's answer as correct.

Comment: @28space_junkiee You're welcome! As for the binary search question. That should be a separate question. First think about it, then create another stackoverflow question and provide your attempt and what didn't work with your attempt

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of 10,000 Shoes each with a random price like this:

```js
class Shoe {
  constructor(name, price, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
var names = ["Nike AirMax 90", "Jordan Retro 1", "Jadon Doc Martens"]; // can be more
var types = ["Casual", "Athletic", "Formal"]; // can be more
   
var shoes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  shoes.push(new Shoe(
    names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length) -1], 
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000), 
    types[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length) -1])
  );
}

console.log(shoes)
```

This will let you do the bubble sort exercise. The data might not be very realistic but that probably doesn't really matter I assume.

Comment: ok and would this still be considered an array of objects? and if i do this would I just delete my class?

Comment: Just copy this over where you currently declare your array of shoes and you will get 10,000 random ones instead of the ones you hardcoded.

Comment: it gives me some undefined ones?

Comment: I must have made a mistake but it looks like you have found some good answers from the other though. I will fix it for future readers just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that creates a random shoe, and call it in a loop.

```js
class Shoe {
  constructor(name, price, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

function random_words(length) {
  let word = "";
  const chars = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  let last_space = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let char = chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    word += last_space ? char.toUpperCase() : char;
    last_space = char == " ";
  }
  return word;
}

function random_shoe() {
  let name = random_words(30);
  let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
  let style = random_words(10);
  return new Shoe(name, price, style);
}

let shoes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  shoes.push(random_shoe());
}

console.log(shoes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Shoe {
  constructor(name, price, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

names = ["Nike", "Adidas", "Puma"];
types = ["Running", "Casual", "Walking", "Training"];
pricesRange = [1, 1000];

const randomShoes = [];
const numberOfShoes = 10;

const randomInteger = () => parseInt(Math.random() * (pricesRange[1] - pricesRange[0]) + pricesRange[0])

const randomArrayItem = arr => {
  const randomIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1));
  return arr[randomIndex];
}

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfShoes; i++) {
  const name = randomArrayItem(names);
  const price = randomInteger();
  const type = randomArrayItem(types);
  const shoe = new Shoe(name, price, type)
  randomShoes.push(shoe);
}

randomShoes.forEach(shoe => console.log(shoe));
```

Comment: would this still be considered an array of objects and sorry I'm a complete newbie so what does 'const' mean?

Comment: Yes this is an array of objects. const is similar to var except variables declared with const may not be assigned a new values or it will give an error.